# hoe to round a number of power 10 to 5 decimals

Tags: java, math, rounding

I am using Java to do some calculations. The results come in a complicated format like "9.2233720368E11" .

I want to round this number to 5 decimals and keep the power of 10 "E11".
I tried this code

```
rounded = Math.round(subnitOut * 100000.0)/100000.0;
```

which works fine until the power of 10 (E) appears in the results, then it doesn't work at all.

Is there a method to do this directly? Or I have to deal with it as a text and use text methods to trim the unwanted numbers.

Comment: Your approach doesn't work because of floating point precision, so the division and multiplication won't have the desired effect for large numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format a floating point number in scientific notation so that it only shows 5 decimal places while retaining the exponent, you can use the following:

```
double d = 9.2233720368E11;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00000E0");

System.out.println(df.format(d));

>> 9.22337E11
```

As you can tell, the number of `0`s passed to the `DecimalFormat` constructor (before `E`) determines how many decimal places to print.  The amount of `0`s appended to `E` determines how many digits to use for the exponent.  This rounds the `double` as well, so `9.2233760368E11` would yield `9.22338E11`.

EDIT: I've created a method as well in case you need to format results differently.

```
public static String format(double d, int numDecimalPlaces, int numExponentDigits) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("0.%0");

    sb.append(numDecimalPlaces);
    sb.append("d");
    sb.append("E");
    sb.append("%0");
    sb.append(numExponentDigits);
    sb.append("d");

    return new DecimalFormat(String.format(sb.toString(), 0, 0)).format(d);
}
```

Usage:

```
double d = 9.2233760368E11;

System.out.println(format(d, 5, 1));

>> 9.22338E11
```